# CMake INSTALL and RENAME cannot find file

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to make and install a config.cmake file for the project that I'm building, and the install part isn't working because apparently it can't find the file. I was originally using the INSTALL command from cmake, and when that didn't work I tried file( RENAME ... ) because I have a little more experience with it - neither seem to work. I've verified that the file is being made in the correct location and with the expected filename.

This is the relevant part of the CMakeLists.txt:

```
################################################################################
# Build the config.cmake file for finding project information
################################################################################
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake "set(${PROJECT_NAME}_PROTO_DIR ${PROTO_MAIN_DIR})\n")
file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake "set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/;${PROTO_GEN_DIR})\n")
file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake "set(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/)\n")
file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake "set(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_LIBRARIES})\n")

message( "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: " ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
message( "PROJECT_NAME: " ${PROJECT_NAME} )

#INSTALL(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake DESTINATION ~/CMake/Modules/)
file(RENAME ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake ~/CMake/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake)
```

Here's the relevant output when I try to rune cmake:

```
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /home/ava/workspace/frontseat_drivers/build
PROJECT_NAME: frontseat
CMake Error at src/frontseat/CMakeLists.txt:47 (file):
  file RENAME failed to rename

    /home/ava/workspace/frontseat_drivers/build/frontseatConfig.cmake

  to

    ~/CMake/Modules/frontseatConfig.cmake

  because: No such file or directory
```

and here's output confirming that the file is where I expect with the name that I expect:

```
ava@3b97b310abf0:~/workspace/frontseat_drivers/build$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ava ava 12219 Jun 13 19:04 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 5 ava ava  4096 Jun 13 18:48 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ava ava  2250 Jun 13 15:41 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ava ava   315 Jun 14 12:30 frontseatConfig.cmake
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ava ava  6397 Jun 13 18:48 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x. 5 ava ava    98 Jun 13 18:48 src
```

What would cause CMake not to be able to see the file?

Comment: I guess the error is about `~/CMake/Modules/frontseatConfig.cmake` where CMake doesn't resolve `~` part. You may use `$ENV{HOME}` for user's home directory. Note, that `CMake/Modules/` is a wrong place for project's configuration files (`*Config.cmake`) - such files are usually shipped with the project's installation. But you may place `Find*.cmake` into `CMake/Modules`.

Comment: Thank you - that was exactly my problem. Can you please post this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably about **destination file** `~/CMake/Modules/frontseatConfig.cmake`. It is because CMake doesn't interpret `~` part, so it cannot resolve the path correctly.

Instead of `~` use  `$ENV{HOME}` for point to the user's home directory.